# Clicking a div with JS or jQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, click

a website has a div that is being used as a button. I am trying to click the button using .click(). Somehow there is no reaction at all.

```
<div class="make_button make_button_hover" data-target="#myModal_wait" data-toggle="modal" style="color: green; border: 2px solid green;">Accept!</div>
```

I can safely select the div via:

```
var buttonToClick = document.getElementById("actionBox").firstChild;
```

(This is the parent div, firstChild is the button itself. The class changes depending on some actions on the website.)

buttonToClick.click() doesn't show any reaction, like it usualy would. I guess it has something to do with the modal thing.

I recorded a GET request that is running when I click the button manually. This is the data that is being sent:

https://gyazo.com/26f2696c7d4d52fbd6bc00dfd0b1f483

pointer-click and browser-info sounds a bit like a captcha thing, is this right?

How would I click that button? I didn't find help on google.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Change it to <btn class="make_button..."

Comment: Hey and thank you! I just tried, but it doesn't change anything. It is not my website by the way - this click is supposed to be part of a chrome extension.

Comment: buttonToClick.trigger('click')